# Clojure - Map through all levels

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to create a map function that goes through every element and applies an operation. It is simply like a the `map` function, but goes in depth.

The function takes two args; one function and one for the arguments.

Here is what I have so far:

```
(defn go-through
 [op & args]
   (if-not (sequential? (first args))
     (apply op args)
     (apply (partial map go-through op) args)))
```

And I knew that the last line wouldn't work, even without calling it. But I don't know how any other way.

Suggestions?

---

Perhaps I'm limiting the uses for such a function.

Sample:

```
user=> (go-through + 1 2)
3
user=> (go-through + [1 2] [3 4])
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.core$_PLUS_     clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:494)
```

I was expecting `[4 6]`

The idea is for this applicable with any function that operates on single elements, and not sequentials.

Comment: could you include a sample input and output? should it preserve the tree structure or produce a seq?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt, it should preserve the tree structure.

Comment: do you want [4 6] or [3 7] ?

Comment: I want `[4 6]`. It maps the function across the two vectors. I'm not looking for a `reduce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this is solution for you:

```
(defn go-through [op & args]
   (if-not (sequential? (first args))
     (apply op args)
     (apply map op args)))

(go-through + 1 2 3)
-> 6

(go-through + [1 2] [3 4] [5 6])
-> (9 12)
```

Version 2 (fixed original example)

```
(defn go-through [op & args]
   (if-not (sequential? (first args))
     (apply op args)
     (apply map (partial go-through op) args)))

(go-through + [[1 2] [3 4]] [[5 6] [7 8]])
-> ((6 8) (10 12))
```

Comment: @Zchpyvr There was one mistake. I've just fixed.

Comment: Sorry, actually, this solution doesn't work beyond a depth of two.

Comment: @Zchpyvr Could you give an example? Anyway I've added another version.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your first line will neither work, as the "if" condition is just checking if the first argument is a sequential, and then calling op will all arguments.

I would recommend using http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html or look at its code ;)

Comment: .... for some reason, the way I use it, the first line works, it's just the "else". Please see the output above.